# How remove some fields of referenced entity from criteria query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Suppose we have entity A that contains a list of entities with type B (with lazy initialization).
Entity B has one BLOB field and some other, that doesn't contain much data.

How can I, using hibernate criteria query, get entity A with it's fields and each A-entity with list of Bs, but every B-entity without the BLOB field ?

Also, I do not want to extract As and iterate them to get Bs. (I now, how to use 'Projections' to extract just Bs with required fields).

Here is some code sample:

A-entity:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "A")  
public class A implements Serializable {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> list = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

B-entity:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "B")  
public class B implements Serializable {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", nullable = false)
    private A a;
}
```

Comment: please add your code and give data clearly

Comment: @SubbaramiReddy, Done. Can you help ?

Comment: Projections are exists for this purpose : either you load full a entity, or select some field using projection. If you load only some field how would hibernate know which field to persist/update ? Use projection.

Comment: @jpprade Can you write some code, please ? I know how to user projections, if I'm loading B's directly, but here I load A's, so it's not obvious.